# Springboot return object in api call, get method fails cause of date and time?

Tags: spring-boot, api, postman

Hello I'm creating a Leave Request app where a user can apply leave. Each leave can be link to a user.

I'm facing 2 issues now.

Firstly how do I return my `User` object by calling /leaves api? I want to retrieve the user object details to display on my frontend (e.g. user's name, email, phone number)

Secondly, my /leaves api is returning me an error - is it something to do with how I declare my date and time in the class?

**Leave.java**

```
package com.example.hms.springboothms.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.persistence.*;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "leave")
@Entity
public class Leave {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private Time startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Time endTime;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public Time getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Time startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Time getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Time endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

**Leave.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leave` (
  `leave_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`leave_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `leave`(`leave_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

**LeaveController.java**

```
package com.example.hms.springboothms.controller;

import com.example.hms.springboothms.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.example.hms.springboothms.model.Leave;
import com.example.hms.springboothms.repository.LeaveRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LeaveController {
    @Autowired
    private LeaveRepository leaveRepository;

    @PostMapping("/leaves")
    public Leave addLeave(@RequestBody Leave leave) {
        return leaveRepository.save(leave);
    }
```

The error I'm facing in postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use java.util.Date in Leave.

   ```
    private java.util.Date creationDate;
   ```
2. you need to annotate each field of type Date with

   ```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date creationDate;
   ```
3. to return the User, you can either return the Leave, which contains a User or
   add a new endpoint /leaves/user/. In both cases you should use @GetMapping instead of @PostMapping

   ```
    @GetMapping("/leaves/{id}")
    public Leave getLeave(@RequestParam(name = "id") String id) {

        return leaveRepository.getById(id);
    }
   ```

or

```
    @GetMapping("/leaves/{id}/user")
    public User getLeave(@RequestParam(name = "id") String id) {

         return leaveRepository.getById(id).getUser();
    }
```